# LocalJumpError while verifying java script alert using ruby watir

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, watir

I am using ruby watir to verify if an alert present .

I use the following code to verify:

```
@browser.alert.exists?
```

I always get the error no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)

How do I avoid this error.

Is it something to do with the gems installed in the machine. I found the script runs properly in another machine. When I viewed the gems list - the gems list is different in two machines. Can anyone suggest which gems to update

Comment: Can you give the full exception - ie the stacktrace? Knowing exactly where the exception is coming from would help identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updates to selenium-webdriver and watir-webdriver solved my problem